# how to convert oracle to_single_byte() in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Oracle

```
select regexp_replace(TO_SINGLE_BYTE('Ａ'),'[^ a-zA-Z]','!!',1,0,'im') from dual;
```

--> Result: `A`

Postgres

```
select regexp_replace('Ａ','[^ a-zA-Z]',' ','ig');
```

--> Result : `!!`

Question: how to get a same result between oracle and Postgres? I'd like get an result as like Oracle.

I tried to search the way to convert this function into Postgres. But the answer is there is no function in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

That letter is Unicode code point U+FF21 (Fullwidth Latin Capital Letter A) and does not match your pattern.

Use the `unaccent` function to convert the character to a regular `A`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

SELECT ascii(unaccent('Ａ'));

 ascii 
-------
    65
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your commenr.You mean unaccent can work as same or simillar with to_single_byte function?